# Downloading Different resources based on screen density

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uiimage, assets

So I know there is a very easy way to have IOS choose the correct sized asset for the currently running device ie: name.png, name@2x.png, name@3x.png.

The app I am creating has hundreds of images that I only want to download if the user were to look at them, or an async fetch from a url:

```
let url = NSURL(string: image.url)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
imageURL.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Do I have to create some method for checking device type or check the screen resolution to see what asset it would have used if the image was in the app. Or is there a helper of some kind for this?

Comment: `UIScreen scale`. Returns 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could approach this.  In the app, you can modify the url path to the image (convert `http://.../image.png` to `http://.../image@2x.png` for example) based on `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`.  There is no automatic scaling by naming your images @2x or @3x - they will be 2 or 3 times larger and you will have to set the UIImageView size properly to display them.

Alternatively, you could pass the scale to the url as a GET parameter `http://.../image.png?imageScale=2` and have your webservice handle the logic and return the correct image.  It is still important to size your UIImageView correctly - to the dimensions of the @1x image.